# How to request publish_stream permission using javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

When I call FB.login() with 'publish_stream' as the requested permission, i.e

```
FB.login( handleLogin, {scope: 'publish_stream'}  );
```

In the dialog that opens, it only says I'm requesting their basic information, and says nothing about the stream_publish permission.

Is this how its expected to work, and when the user clicks accept, he would give this permission, or do I need to then open a second dialog to request this permission somehow? Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you haven't already gotten the publish_stream permission from that user? note that extended permissions like publish_stream are displayed on a second page of the dialog after the initial acceptance

Comment: No I haven't, but it seems like after you click login, then it automatically shows you a dialog saying the app would also like perms to publish. If someone wants to answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extended permissions, including `publish_stream` are displayed on a second page of the dialog - if the user hasn't used your app they must accept the basic permissions you're requesting (including the privacy options for items posted by your app), and then a second page appears asking for the extended permissions

Comment: second pages show error ... why it is not redirected to permission page?